# loader is blocking components from rendering

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm learning react-router-dom through its [documentation tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) and I came across on *[loaders](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader)* in which I attempt to add a blocking code to test if it will halt the render of a component and It did !

```
const routerSample = createBrowserRouter([{
  path: '/',
  element: <div>Hello World</div>,
  loader: async () => {
    await wait(5000) // blocks execution for 5 sec
    return null
  }
}])
```

The loader blocks the rendering of `Hello World` for 5 sec. Any idea how I can render the component/s while the loader fetches the data in parallel.

Comment: Writing loaders with `defer()` and `<Async>` will help with async loading: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/defer. Or maybe better: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of the loader function.

See [loader](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader)

> Each route can define a "loader" function to provide data to the route
> element ***before*** it renders.

Emphasis is mine. The entire point of the loader functions is to fetch any data the page needs and then render the page when the data is ready.

If you don't want to wait for the loader to complete so the route is rendered then move the "loading" logic into the routed component. This allows the route and routed component to mount and render *then* the `useEffect` hook issues the "loader" as intentional side-effect.

```
const loader = async () => {
  await wait(5000);
  return null;
};

const Home = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    loader();
  }, []);

  ... other logic ...

  return <div>Hello World</div>;
};
```

```
const routerSample = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />,
  },
]);
```